# Tabbing with Complex Cell Renderers in AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I'm using ag-grid and want to render a custom component in a cell.  I'm using a cell renderer that could be as simple as the code below.

However, when tabbing, AG-Grid will skip the button and move to the next cell which makes keyboard navigation of complex cell impossible.  Is there a way to have a complex (as in more than a single input) cell renderer and support tabbing?

```
export default class ComplexComponent extends React.Component<{value: string}, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input value={this.props.value}/>
               <button>Do Something Neat</button>
            </div> 
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: [This page of the docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/?framework=all#gsc.tab=0) discusses overriding/customizing tabbing

Comment: Thank you.  however, it doesn't cover how to handle tabbing inside your cell if your custom cell has multiple focussable inputs.

Comment: @RayBooysen Were you able to find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't

Comment: An answer for this question has been posted in 
 a similar question... https://stackoverflow.com/a/77588756/2752433